# If a malicious party attempts to close a Raiden payment channel with incorrect balances, can they steal the deposit?

Tags: security, balances, payments, raiden, state-channels

If a malicious party attempts to close a Raiden payment channel with incorrect balances, can they steal the deposit if the other party doesn't respond?

If they close the channel and transmit that they ended up with the entirety of the deposit as the final balance, (when in reality they had sent half of it to the other party in the channel) will this get added to the blockchain and allow them to effectively steal from the other party?

If there is a time limit for which the other party can challenge the balance, what is the length of time allowed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A party can only attempt to close a channel with a valid state that is signed by both parties. Party A could attempt to close with an outdated state, but there is usually a time-lock where there is an amount of time before the channel is actually closed, meaning party B could then submit a later state that was signed by both parties. The length of the timelock is completely dependent on the implementation and can vary widely